# How to get `ts` program on the mac

Tags: command-line, homebrew, script

On linux there is a great command line program `ts`. It adds a timestamp to the beginning of each line of input.

Here is an example (on some linux machine):

```
root@227ee318bbc1:~# echo -e '1\n2\n3'
1
2
3
root@227ee318bbc1:~# echo -e '1\n2\n3' | ts
Apr 19 18:59:52 1
Apr 19 18:59:52 2
Apr 19 18:59:52 3
root@227ee318bbc1:~#
```

But there is no such program on my mac:

```
bessarabov@air:~$ echo -e '1\n2\n3' | ts
-bash: ts: command not found
```

And there is no program with such name in brew.

How can I get `ts` program on my mac?

Comment: Seems to be rather easy to solve with a shell script :-) What does `file $(type -p ts)` return on your Linux system?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Try `brew install moreutils` and then run the `ts` command. `moreutils` installs a bunch of things.

https://rentes.github.io/unix/utilities/2015/07/27/moreutils-package/

Comment: This clashes with other packages like `parallel` and `sponge` 